# Multistep Form validation remove on no 4 step

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

i make a multistep form with step validation required i apply validation on this multistep form but now i want to remove validation required from no 4 step because in no 4 step i need to add some input field and first three step i add some radio input kindly check my code.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentStep = 0;
  var steps = $('.step');
  
  // Show the first step
  $(steps[currentStep]).addClass('activee'); 
  // Next button click event
  $('.next').click(function() {  
    if (validateStep(currentStep)) {
      $(steps[currentStep]).removeClass('activee');
      currentStep++;
      $(steps[currentStep]).addClass('activee');
    }
      
  });
  
  // Previous button click event
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    $(steps[currentStep]).removeClass('activee');
    currentStep--;
    $(steps[currentStep]).addClass('activee');
  });
  
  // Submit button click event
  $('.submit').click(function() {
    if (validateStep(currentStep)) {
      alert('Form submitted successfully!');
    }
  });
    
      // Function to validate each step
  function validateStep(step) {
    var checkboxes = $(steps[step]).find('input[type="radio"]'); 
    var checked = checkboxes.is(':focus');
    
    if (!focus) {
      alert('Please select at least one option');
      return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
});
```

this is HTML code kindly check

**HTML**

```
          <div class="step">
          1
                  <button class="prev btncoss0">Previous</button>
    <button class="next btncoss">Next</button>
          </div>
          
              <div class="step">
          2
                  <button class="prev btncoss0">Previous</button>
    <button class="next btncoss">Next</button>
          </div>
          
              <div class="step">
          3
                  <button class="prev btncoss0">Previous</button>
    <button class="next btncoss">Next</button>
          </div>
          
              <div class="step">
          4
                  <button class="prev btncoss0">Previous</button>
    <button class="next btncoss">Next</button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `validateStep()`, just make this the first line:

```
if(step === 3) return true;
```